# Calculate an inductive coil parameters for EMP generator

Tags: high-voltage, amperage, inductance, pulse, electromagnetic

For research purposes, I want to calculate an inductive coil parameters suitable to work with high voltage and low amperage impulses, produced by power source (handheld high voltage generator) that can produce short high voltage and low amperage impulses, about 53 million volts and 1-3 mA. The coil should generate short electromagnetic pulse (EMP) which need be focused to a beam for greater efficiency. The most difficult task is probably, how to get EMP focused to a beam without using the complex technology and special materials, just with common DIY parts & components that can be purchased through Digi-Key. Need calculate also EMP impulse power on the output (theoretical). The required power of EMP impulse should be enough to reliably damage(but not melt) electronic parts from the distance 1-2 in. I need help to calculate an inductive coil and how to get EMP impulse focused.

Comment: Meep.  53 million volts and 1 milliampere is 53kW.  How long are these pulses?  If they are very short, the total energy may be less frightening.  Are you sure you can get parts rated for 53 million volts from Digikey?

Comment: Very short pulse, electrical discharge from stun gun. Manufacturer advertises 53 million volts, but I think the actual voltage it much less.

Comment: That is far less frightening.  It is unlikely that you will really get 53 million volts out of that thing, let alone a couple of milliamperes at the same time.

Comment: Consider this: Breakdown voltage of air is around 30kV per centimeter.  At 53 million volts, you would need like 17 meters of separation between the two terminals to avoid arcing.  Or, one hell of an insulator, but then you won't have much of a stun gun if the terminals are insulated that well.

Comment: Which terminals you mean?

Comment: A stun gun has two terminals that it uses to zap people.  If you want to build up 53 million volts to put across those two terminals, then you need some way to prevent arcing until the 53 million volts has been reached.  It you just put the output of the generator on those terminals, it will never reach 53 million volts.  It will arc at a much (MUCH) lower voltage.  If you some how switch the voltage to the terminals, the I'd like to see the switch and insulators that work at 53 million volts.  So, stun guns don't put out no 53 million volts.

Comment: How do you focus a pulse? Especially a single pulse with almost infinite bandwidth?

Comment: I don't remember details, but seems I've seen somewhere construction that have a long ferrite core, and inductive coil are wound around the central ferrite core.